# Other light flickering after installing new fixture

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, led

I just installed a new dimmable LED wall sconce. There is one other older incandescent light and a handful of outlets on the same circuit. After flipping the breaker back on, I hit the light switch and both lights turned on. The LED took slightly longer to turn on than the other light, and the other one immediately started flickering. While both are turned on, the non-LED light flickers slightly, nearly imperceptibly. However, when I change the brightness of the LED (up or down), the other light flickers aggressively. Also, the overall brightness of the other light is inverse to the LED—-it gets dimmer as the LED gets brighter (while constantly flickering). The house is old but has been renovated, but I don’t know when.

1. is this something I should be concerned about? Any fire hazard?
2. is there an easy fix?

Comment: So you have one dimmer for *both* the incandescent and LED lights together? Dimmers are strange beasts. LEDs and dimmers get even stranger. Is the dimmer old or new? Is the dimmer "LED rated"?

Comment: There is something worrying about "the overall brightness of the other light is inverse to the LED". To me, it almost sounds as if the lights are wired in series instead of in parallel. Flip the breaker back off, pull the light fixtures off the wall (do _NOT_ disconnect any wiring) and get pictures of how the wires are connected, then [edit] your question to include the pics. Something's not right in Denmark...

Answer (score 3):

It is common for an LED to take a second to illuminate when turned on.

The dimming issues are normally the result of a non compatible dimmer used with an LED fixture.  Add in an incandescent and, yes you get really weird dimming action.

Change the dimmer to an LED rated dimmer and get the incandescent bulb changed to a DIMMABLE LED Bulb.

Better yet match both fixtures and the dimmer to have all 3 compatible.

Answer (score 1):

The led bulbs, the drivers, and the dimmer all need to be compatible.  And an LED dimmer is not always compatible with incandescent bulbs.

If you remove the incandescent bulb and the led light works (including the dimming action), then the best bet is to get the same bulb and driver again.

If you don't really need the dimmer, then ditch it.  Consider also that in 5 to 7 years the led is going to be half as bright as it is now.